# Get value between multiple parenthesis with excel/airtable formula

Tags: excel, airtable

I'm trying to get all the content between multiple parenthesis and comma delimiting them. So for example

A1 contains

`thisfile.jpg (/path/to/file.jpg), thisfile2.jpg (/path/to/file2.jpg)`

and B1 should look like

`/path/to/file.jpg, /path/to/file2.jpg`

If it's just one entry I can get what I need with this:

`MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)`

But that only returns the first one, I need to be for each parenthesis. The amount of parenthesis in each row will vary.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are better solutions out there with formulas only. Yet, I cannot help you there. But the following UDF is surely also a feasible solution. Just copy this code into an empty module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetPaths(strTMP As String)

Dim i As Long
Dim varArray As Variant

varArray = Split(strTMP, "(")
For i = LBound(varArray) To UBound(varArray)
    If InStr(1, varArray(i), ")") > 0 Then
        GetPaths = GetPaths & ", " & Mid(varArray(i), 1, InStr(1, varArray(i), ")") - 1)
    End If
Next i
GetPaths = Mid(GetPaths, 3)

End Function
```

Afterwards, you can use this formula in column `B` as follows: `=GetPaths(A1)`.